# Visual Studio Mac doesn't show files in the explorer but the files are in the folder

Tags: visual-studio-mac

So I am rebuilding a VS project in VS Mac, and wanted to rename a class Users_images to UsersImages but get this error

> File or directory name is already in use. Please choose a different one.

The file UsersImages.cs is in the Finder, but not in the project

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with indexation of the files once you rebuild the solution and add more files, but you can add it to the project this way

```
shift + CMD + A
```

or

[image: click from the solution settings select Add -> Add files..]

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio as an external source code editor, the solution explorer was not showing any files or folders at all until I created a .cs file by myself. Is most likely not what you are looking for, but maybe it will help someone else who is a bit lost.